# Discord.js v13 : how i can get the guild members count?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

im trying to modify a channel name when a member enter in the guild, like this:

```js
client.on("member enter", => {

   var membersVar = client.guilds.cache.get("guild id").membercount
   client.channels.get("channel id").Setname(´ membercount: ${membersVar} ´)

})
```

↑ **just a example who dont work, but this is a part of my real javascript code:**

```js
//#region MEMBER CONFIGURATION

var MembersInTheServer = client.guilds.cache.get('guild id here').memberCount

//#endregion

//#region NEW MEMBER IN THE GUILD

client.on("guildMemberAdd", async (member) => {

    client.channels.cache.get('1026818809509728336').setName(`・ᴍembers・❬${MembersInTheServer}❭`)

});

//#endregion
```

#### lets place " console.log(MembersInTheServer) "

- [ console log ]

```
var MembersInTheServer = client.guilds.cache.get('GUILD_ID').memberCount
                                                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'memberCount')
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Edtecsoft\Pictures\Bots caio\Avisador\index.js:525:68)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1173:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:838:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:18:47

Node.js v18.8.0
```

#### lets place " console.log(client.guilds.cache.get('GUILD_ID')) "

- [ console log ]

```
undefined
```

#### conclusion: client can't find the guild with the **get()** method and the GUILD_ID

obs:

> my complete code have 734 lines

Comment: If `undefined` is returned from `get()` it means that guild is not cached. You will need to fetch it: `client.guilds.fetch()` and resolve the promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the `MembersInTheServer` in the `event`, not out of it. In this way, It updates when a user joins the server.

```js
        client.on("guildMemberAdd", async (member) => {
            if (member.guild.id === 'guild_id') {
                const MembersInTheServer = member.guild.memberCount;
                let channel = client.channels.cache.get('1026818809509728336');
                if (!channel) return console.log('Could not find the channel');
                channel.setName(`・Members・❬${MembersInTheServer}❭`);
            } else return;
        });
```

Comment: sure, member.guild is a good way